# How to receive file from multiple client at a time over TCP connection using C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am having a server and multiple clients in my project. Server need to send the files by request, and it store the files from clients. I have coding, that connects with multiple clients but receives one file at time. Other file store requests will proceed after the previous file received completely.

My files size is around 200 MB. So it takes more time to respond all clients. How i will solve this. Any one help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    byte[] Echo;
    byte[] a;
    Thread t1;
    int flag = 0;
    string receivedPath = "yok";
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    private string fileName;
    public Form1()
    {
        t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListening));
        t1.Start();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;

        public const int BufferSize = 8069;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    }

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    public void StartListening()
    {

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[8069];
        IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(ipEnd);
            listener.Listen(100);
            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
                allDone.WaitOne();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SetText(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        flag = 0;


    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int fileNameLen = 1;
        String content = String.Empty;
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {

                if (flag == 0)
                {

                    fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                    fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fileNameLen);
                    receivedPath = @"D:\" + fileName;
                    flag++;

                }

                if (flag >= 1)
                {
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath, FileMode.Append));
                    if (flag == 1)
                    {
                        writer.Write(state.buffer, 4 + fileNameLen, bytesRead - (4 + fileNameLen));
                        flag++;
                    }
                    else
                    writer.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    writer.Close();
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                allDone.Set();
                Invoke(new MyDelegate(LabelWriter));
            }
        }
       catch
        {
        }
    }
    public void LabelWriter()
    {
        label1.Text = "Data has been received " + fileName;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        t1.Abort();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger your allDone event within the AcceptCallback method. Immidiatly after accepting a client, you can spin of a process that is communicating with that client while in the meantime start listening for the next client.

Comment: If i got two file store request at a same time means how it store both file at a same time?